# how to change an image via javascript when user clicks on an image

Tags: javascript, image, click

E.g html:

```
<DIV>Here is some text..</DIV>
<DIV><IMG src="image1.png">one</DIV>
```

When user clicks on the image (image1.png) I want to change the image to image2.png?

How can I do this with plain javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the javascript code that you've already tried? Did you try searching Google? This is a very simple problem.

Comment: I thought for sure I'd easily find a duplicate, but I gave up.

Comment: @Matt: I did not spend time on google. I spent some time on SO and somehow was running into much more complex scenarios. I did try google afterwards and found relevant hits. Thanks to all for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
<IMG src="image1.png" onclick='this.src="image2.png"'>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Hjg52/)

***Pure JS***

```
document.getElementById('img').onclick=function() {
    this.src='image2.png';
};
```

Comment: While this works, could we not use inline javascript?

Comment: @MattDiamant, Certainly, but I'm too lazy & tired, even copied portion of comment

Answer (score 1):

```
<img ... onclick="this.src = 'image2.png'" />
```

---

In response to your comment, I don't have a pure JS click handler for you, but with jQuery it would look like this:

```
$('img').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'image2.png');
});
```

Comment: While this works, could we not use inline javascript?

Comment: Certainly, but I'm too lazy to Google event handlers for you. I use jQuery, which makes this type of thing MUCH easier to write from memory. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<DIV>Here is some text..</DIV>
<DIV><IMG id="image1" src="image1.png">one</DIV>

<script type="text/javascript">

   window.onload = (function(oldLoad) {
     return function() {
        oldLoad && oldLoad();
        // wire up image event handler
        document.getElementById("image1").onClick = function() {
          this.src = "image2.png";
        }

     }
   })(window.onload)

</script>
```

Edit - After my comment:

There are times where many people cannot utilize the power of jQuery.  The OP wanted to know in his comment what the purpose of the oldLoad was and I wanted to provide a detailed answer.

Basically what I have written here is something "similar" to jQuery's $(document).ready(). and Here is how I would utilize this example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var Core = {
     windowLoadEvent: function(oldLoad, newLoad) {
       return function() {
         //check if the window.onload already has a function attached if so then execute
         oldLoad && oldLoad();

         //check if the newload has a function attached if so then execute
         newLoad && newLoad();
     },
     myNewLoadEvent: function() {
       document.getElementById("image1").onClick = function() {
         this.src = "image2.png";
       }    
       //wireup whatever else is needed.
     }
   }

   window.onload = Core.windowLoadEvent(window.onload, Core.myNewLoadEvent)
</script>
```

Comment: that's beautiful `window.onload` but what's purpose of `oldLoad`? Please help me to understand it

Comment: @Satpal   I actually messed up...the parameter passed to the onload function should be oldLoad.  Now the purpose of this is to mimic something similar to the $(document).ready() function in jQuery.  Basically you can bind your events from Javascript instead of handling your event binding using inline html (ie <div onclick="javascript:...">).   The code writen above is a simple closure statement that can assist you.  I will edit the answer to show you an somewhat advanced way to utilize this.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this ([**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2B2CM/1/))

**HTML:**

```
<div id="images">
    <div><IMG src="image1_url" />one</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var images = document.getElementById('images');
images.onclick = function(e){
    var event = e || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    target.src="image2_url";
};
```